# Add section titles to list of custom environment

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, environments, koma-script, tocloft

In the following MWE, how can I add section titles into `\listofusecase`? I'd like the use cases to be listed below their respective section titles in the same way as subsections are listed in the regular `\tableofcontents`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{multicol,tocloft,xcolor}
\newlistof{usecase}{cas}{}

\newlength\lcolwidth\setlength{\lcolwidth}{1.35cm}

\newcommand{\uchead}[1]{%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{\bfseries\sffamily#1}}

\newenvironment{usecase}[1]{
    \refstepcounter{usecase}\setlength\parindent{0pt}
    \colorbox{gray!20}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep][l]{\uchead{Case~\theusecase~--~#1}}}\par\hrule
    \phantomsection\addcontentsline{cas}{usecase}{\protect\numberline{\theusecase}#1}\par}
    {\bigbreak}


\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{usecase}{Use Case 1}
    Foo bar
\end{usecase}

\begin{usecase}{Use Case 2}
    Foo bar
\end{usecase}

\begin{usecase}{Use Case 3}
    Foo bar
\end{usecase}


\section{Section 2}

\begin{usecase}{Use Case 4}
    Foo bar
\end{usecase}

\begin{usecase}{Use Case 5}
    Foo bar
\end{usecase}


\section{Section 3}

\begin{usecase}{Use Case 6}
    Foo bar
\end{usecase}

\begin{usecase}{Use Case 7}
    Foo bar
\end{usecase}

\begin{usecase}{Use Case 8}
    Foo bar
\end{usecase}

\begin{usecase}{Use Case 9}
    Foo bar
\end{usecase}

\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{List of use cases}]
    \listofusecase
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `tocloft` and `KOMA`? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Apparently, the two are not compatible (see the comments to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394082/why-does-loading-the-tocloft-package-break-my-two-column-toc?noredirect=1#comment979565_394082)).

Comment: Yes, it's a well-known fact that they are incompatible, that's why I don't use KOMA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add

```
\renewcommand*{\addsectiontocentry}[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{section}{#1}{#2}%
  \addxcontentsline{cas}{section}[{#1}]{#2}%
}
```

to the preamble of your MWE.

[image]

But I would suggest to remove package `tocloft`: You could use the commands of KOMA-Script package `tocbasic` to define a new list and to format the entries.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\DeclareNewTOC[
  type=usecase,
  tocentryindent=0pt,
  name=Case,
  listname=List of Use Cases
]{cas}
\BeforeStartingTOC[cas]{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\AfterStartingTOC[cas]{\end{multicols}}
\newcounter{usecase}

\newenvironment{usecase}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{usecase}%
    \addxcontentsline{cas}{usecase}[\theusecase]{#1}%
    \setlength\parindent{0pt}%
    \colorbox{gray!20}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep][l]{%
      \uchead{Case~\theusecase~--~#1}}}%
    \par\hrule\par
  }
  {\bigbreak}
\newcommand{\uchead}[1]{%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{\bfseries\sffamily#1}}

\renewcommand*{\addsectiontocentry}[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{section}{#1}{#2}%
  \addxcontentsline{cas}{section}[{#1}]{#2}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 1}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 2}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 3}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\section{Section 2}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 4}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 5}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\section{Section 3}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 6}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 7}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 8}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 9}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\end{multicols}

\listofusecases
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is great! I learned a lot from your answer. One thing I didn't foresee in my question: Is it possible to add section titles to `\listofusecases` only if the section contains a `usecase` environment? (I realize this might be difficult. If it is I might ask a new question.)

Comment: Maybe its better to ask a new question.

Comment: See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394170/remove-section-titles-from-list-of-custom-environment-if-section-doesnt-contain).