# Why does loading the tocloft package break my two-column toc?

Tags: table-of-contents, multicol, tocloft

In this MWE, how come my two-column table of contents gets stretched out into one column upon loading the [`tocloft`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft?lang=en) package? How can I prevent this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\end{multicols}}
\tableofcontents

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.2}
\subsection{Subsection 1.3}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 2.1}
\subsection{Subsection 2.2}
\subsection{Subsection 2.3}
\section{Section 3}
\subsection{Subsection 3.1}
\subsection{Subsection 3.2}
\subsection{Subsection 3.3}
\section{Section 4}
\subsection{Subsection 4.1}
\subsection{Subsection 4.2}
\subsection{Subsection 4.3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you search the site, you will notice that tocloft is probably not compatible with the class you are using.

Comment: @daleif I see. Is there a compatible package that provides similar functionality as `tocloft` for creating lists of custom counters as done in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394079/add-section-titles-to-list-of-custom-environment)?

Comment: No idea, I never use the koma classes. Other answers suggest trying the tocstyle package. Not sure if it adds the same features.

Comment: The class you are using can do it. Have a look for `tocbasic` in the manual.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks for the tip. I did get it to work but somehow, separate list entries don't start on a new line. Rather the list looks like a continuous piece of text. I declared `\DeclareNewTOC{cases}` and added `\phantomsection\addxcontentsline{cases}{usecase}{\protect\numberline{\theusecase}#1}\par}` to my custom usecase environment. Can you by any chance see what the problem is?

Comment: I don't see the point in using  `\addxcontentsline`. Doesn't `tocbasic` do that by itself? Hint: Search for `DeclareNewTOC` on this website.

Comment: @Johannes_B I do believe `\addxcontentsline` is essential to solving my problem. By the way, adding the optional argument `\DeclareNewTOC[type=usecase]{cases}` solved the problem of new list entries not starting on a new line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\begin{document}

\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\end{multicols}}
\tableofcontents

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.2}
\subsection{Subsection 1.3}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 2.1}
\subsection{Subsection 2.2}
\subsection{Subsection 2.3}
\section{Section 3}
\subsection{Subsection 3.1}
\subsection{Subsection 3.2}
\subsection{Subsection 3.3}
\section{Section 4}
\subsection{Subsection 4.1}
\subsection{Subsection 4.2}
\subsection{Subsection 4.3}

\end{document}
```

But you should probably check the Koma doc for tocbasic/tocstyle.

Comment: `tocstyle` is ... kinda ... dead.

Comment: @Johannes_B ah ok. `texdoc -l koma` brings up dozens of entries but now all point to a single html page giving basically only a link to `scrguien.pdf` and then one has to search inside pdf. I only checked there were indeed hits for `tocstyle` in this manual, after getting the impression `tocbasic` did not provide `tocloft` style customization.

Comment: (cont.) reading a bit more I see that `tocbasic` is destined to incorporate the `tocstyle` functionalities in future. (and perhaps already does...)