# Remove section titles from list of custom environment if section doesn't contain said environment

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, environments, koma-script, tocbasic

This is a follow-up question to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394079/add-section-titles-to-list-of-custom-environment).

In the following MWE, how can I remove section and subsection titles from the `\listofusecases` if said section or subsection doesn't contain a single `usecase` environment? Also, how can I remove the page numbers and dotted lines on (sub-)section lines?

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\DeclareNewTOC[
    type=usecase,
    listname=List of Use Cases,
    tocentryentryformat=\sffamily,
    tocentrypagenumberformat=\sffamily,
    indent=6ex
]{lou}
\renewcommand*{\addsectiontocentry}[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{section}{#1}{#2}%
  \addxcontentsline{lou}{section}{\large#2}%
}
\renewcommand*{\addsubsectiontocentry}[2]{%
    \addtocentrydefault{subsection}{#1}{#2}%
    \addxcontentsline{lou}{subsection}{\textbf{\sffamily #2}}%
}

\newcounter{usecase}
\newenvironment{usecase}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{usecase}%
    \addxcontentsline{lou}{usecase}[\theusecase]{#1}%
    \setlength\parindent{0pt}%
    \colorbox{gray!20}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep][l]{%
      \uchead{Case~\theusecase~--~#1}}}%
    \par\hrule\par
  }
  {\bigbreak}
\newcommand{\uchead}[1]{%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{\bfseries\sffamily#1}}


\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 2.1}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 1}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\subsection{Subsection 2.2}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 2}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 3}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\section{Section 3}
\section{Section 4}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 4}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 5}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\section{Section 5}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 6}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 7}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 8}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 9}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\section{Section 6}

\end{multicols}

\BeforeStartingTOC[lou]{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\AfterStartingTOC[lou]{\end{multicols}}
\listofusecases

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can do such things by using `etoc` package rather than `koma-script` facilities; however in the long run, it is probably better to stick to the latter as they are class-provided.

Comment: @jfbu So you're saying this _is_ possible using just `koma-script` but might be more difficult than using `etoc`?

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean to imply it is possible with `koma-script`. I don't know if it is or not and could not provide a `koma-script` based solution due to my lack of knowledge. (I guess not printing dots etc.. is ok, the more demanding point is to avoid section/subsection without use cases)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a suggestion which bases on https://komascript.de/node/1949:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\DeclareNewTOC[
  tocentrylevel=\subsubsectiontocdepth,
  type=usecase,
  name=Case,
  listname=List of Use Cases,
  tocentryformat=\sffamily,
  tocentrypagenumberformat=\sffamily,
  tocentryindent=6ex% < name of the option changed
]{lou}
\BeforeStartingTOC[lou]{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\AfterStartingTOC[lou]{\end{multicols}}
\newcounter{usecase}

\newenvironment{usecase}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{usecase}%
    \addxcontentsline{lou}{usecase}[\theusecase]{#1}%
    \setlength\parindent{0pt}%
    \colorbox{gray!20}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep][l]{%
      \uchead{Case~\theusecase~--~#1}}}%
    \par\hrule\par
  }
  {\bigbreak}
\newcommand{\uchead}[1]{%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{\bfseries\sffamily#1}}

% bases on https://komascript.de/node/1949
\makeatletter

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  level=\sectiontocdepth,
  indent=0pt,
  numwidth=1.5em,
  entryformat=\usekomafont{disposition},
  pagenumberformat=\@gobble,
  linefill=\hfill
]{tocline}{lousection}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  level=\subsectiontocdepth,
  indent=1.5em,
  numwidth=2.3em,
  entryformat=\usekomafont{disposition},
  pagenumberformat=\@gobble,
  linefill=\hfill
]{tocline}{lousubsection}

\newcounter{sectionID}
\renewcommand{\thesectionID}{secID@\arabic{sectionID}}

\newcommand*\sectionhas@original@addcontentsline{}
\let\sectionhas@original@addcontentsline\addcontentsline
\renewcommand*{\addcontentsline}[1]{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\sectionhas{\thesectionID}{#1}}%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\subsectionhas{\thesubsection}{#1}}%
  \sectionhas@original@addcontentsline{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\sectionhas}[2]{%
  \global\@namedef{sectionhas@#1@#2}{true}%
}
\newcommand*{\subsectionhas}[2]{%
  \global\@namedef{subsectionhas@#1@#2}{true}%
}

\renewcommand*{\addsectiontocentry}[2]{%
  \stepcounter{sectionID}%
  \addtocentrydefault{section}{#1}{#2}%
  \ifundefinedorrelax{sectionhas@\thesectionID @lou}
    {}{\addxcontentsline{lou}{lousection}{#2}}%
}
\renewcommand*{\addsubsectiontocentry}[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{subsection}{#1}{#2}%
  \ifundefinedorrelax{subsectionhas@\thesubsection @lou}
    {}{\addxcontentsline{lou}{lousubsection}{#2}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 2.1}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 1}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\subsection{Subsection 2.2}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 2}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 3}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\section{Section 3}
\section{Section 4}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 4}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 5}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\section{Section 5}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 6}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 7}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 8}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 9}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\section{Section 6}
\end{multicols}

\listofusecases
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get

[image]

Note you have to delete the `aux` file if the structure of the document is changed.

Comment: Works great! And without any extra packages. I'm impressed.

Answer (score 4):

Here is with [etoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc). The challenge is to get to know whether a section or subsection contains a `usecase`. For this the TOC is executed a first time, à la `etoc` only to extract that information. Then it is executed for the real thing.

I know little about the macros used by KOMA for typesetting the TOC, and I decided to examin a trace to hack into the "dotfill" part. Indeed, there seems to be no option to deactivate them for subsections in scrartcl class.

With `etoc` any design can be achieved but this requires work and to fit it with the class layout one would need to extract from its code the macros to use, which I had no time to investigate.

Thus I followed method "Another compatibility mode" of manual. As I use `\etocsavedsectiontocline` etc.. , this requires `etoc 1.08k` at least, else one does `\let\savedsectiontocline\l@section` etc...

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoc}

\newcounter{usecase}
\etocsetlevel{usecase}{6}
\newenvironment{usecase}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{usecase}%
    \etoctoccontentsline{usecase}{\string\numberline{\theusecase}#1}%
    \setlength\parindent{0pt}%
    \colorbox{gray!20}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep][l]{%
      \uchead{Case~\theusecase~--~#1}}}%
    \par\hrule\par
  }
  {\bigbreak}
\newcommand{\uchead}[1]{%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{\bfseries\sffamily#1}}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifsubsectionhasusecase
\newif\ifsectionhasusecase

% \cas@list will be storage for a sequence of 1 and 0 indicating
% which section or subsection contain subcases
% \cas@list will be obtained via a first \tableofcontents
\def\cas@popfirst{\expandafter\cas@popfirst@\cas@list\relax}
\def\cas@popfirst@#1#2\relax{\def\cas@tmp{#1}\def\cas@list{#2}}

\newcommand\listofusecases{%
    \begingroup
      \etocsetlevel{subsubsection}{6}%
      \etocsetlevel{usecase}{3}%
      \etocsetstyle{section}
          {\sectionhasusecasefalse\toks\tw@{}\etocskipfirstprefix}
          {\ifsectionhasusecase\toks@\expandafter{\the\toks@1}%
             \else
                        \toks@\expandafter{\the\toks@0}%
           \fi
           \toks@\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
            {\expandafter\the\expandafter\toks@\the\toks\tw@}%
          }
          {\sectionhasusecasefalse\toks\tw@{}}
          {\ifsectionhasusecase\toks@\expandafter{\the\toks@1}%
             \else
                        \toks@\expandafter{\the\toks@0}%
           \fi
           \toks@\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
            {\expandafter\the\expandafter\toks@\the\toks\tw@}%
           \sectionhasusecasefalse}%
      \etocsetstyle{subsection}
          {\subsectionhasusecasefalse\toks\tw@{}\etocskipfirstprefix}
          {\ifsubsectionhasusecase\toks\tw@\expandafter{\the\toks\tw@1}%
             \else
                        \toks\tw@\expandafter{\the\toks\tw@0}%
           \fi
          }
          {\subsectionhasusecasefalse}
          {\ifsubsectionhasusecase\toks\tw@\expandafter{\the\toks\tw@1}%
             \else
                        \toks\tw@\expandafter{\the\toks\tw@0}%
           \fi
           \subsectionhasusecasefalse
           }%
      \etocsetstyle{usecase}{\subsectionhasusecasetrue\sectionhasusecasetrue}{}{}{}%
      %
      \etocsettocstyle
         {\toks@{}}%
         {\xdef\cas@list{\the\toks@}}%
      % fetch whether units include subcases
      \tableofcontents
      % now for the real thing. But I don't want to dig into KOMA code
      % for typesetting TOCs.
      %\KOMAoptions{subsectionentrywithoutdots}% does not exist!
      % and even if existed would it obey group scope ?
      \etocsetstyle{section}
                   {}
                   {\cas@popfirst}
                   {\if1\cas@tmp
                      \etocsavedsectiontocline
                       {\numberline{\etocnumber}\etocname}{}%
                    \fi}
                   {}%
      \etocsetstyle{subsection}
                   {}
                   {\cas@popfirst}
                   {\if1\cas@tmp
                    {% hack to avoid dots (I had to dig into code expansion...)
                      \@namedef{\@backslashchar TOCLineLeaderFill}[####1]{\hfill}%
                      \etocsavedsubsectiontocline
                        {\numberline{\etocnumber}\etocname}{}%
                    }\fi}
                   {}%
      \etocsetstyle{usecase}
                   {}
                   {}
                   {% use KOMA style for subsubsections
                    \etocsavedsubsubsectiontocline
                       {\numberline{\etocnumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}%
                   }
                   {}%
      \etocsettocstyle{\section*{List of use cases}
                       \begin{multicols}{2}\sffamily}
                      {\end{multicols}}%
      \tableofcontents
    \endgroup
}

\makeatletter


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 2.1}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 1}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\subsection{Subsection 2.2}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 2}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 3}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\section{Section 3}
\section{Section 4}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 4}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 5}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\section{Section 5}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 6}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 7}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 8}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\begin{usecase}{Use Case 9}
  Foo bar
\end{usecase}
\section{Section 6}

\end{multicols}

\clearpage % only for nicer view
\listofusecases


\end{document}
```

`etoc` uses *only one file*. Thus I issued a regular `\tableofcontents` to check it was not contaminated by the `usecase` entries.

[image]

Comment: there is whitespace `1      Use Case 1` etc... but this due to `subsubsection` KOMA Toc style. If you know how to customize that, it will be fixed. Assuming (which I don't doubt) KOMA allows such things locally, so one does not have to worry to reestablish defaults later. Anyway, the main TOC was issued at start of document.

Comment: better looking result from `\vfill\hrule height0pt \end{multicols}`  (or rather `\raggedcolumns\end{multicols}`) and also `\columnsep` should be increased.

Comment: I have fixed a bug from initial version. I had been using groups but I took them out at some point; using only one toggle is not possible then. New way uses two. (the bug would show if at end of a section containing usecase environments, there was a subsection without).

Comment: You can also avoid the whitespace visible in image if using `\etocsavedsubsubsectiontocline{\makebox[1.5em][l]{\etocnumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}`, i.e. avoiding the `\numberline`, but typesetting the number directly as one wishes.